# Use URL to change links (html tags in URL links)

Tags: javascript, jquery, url

I am trying to write a script, that happens like this:
1. someone clicks on a link from an email as such: http://www.domain.com/page/?e=email@usersemail.com
2. when they land on the page, it detects the URL has an email address associated with it and removes existing href and uses onclick function with new links. (I tried replacing the href attribute, but that didn't work)

This is the code I have:

```
$(function(){
    var channel = 'default';
    var url = window.location.href;

    if(url.match(/e=(.*)/)) {
        channel = url.match(/e=(.*)/)[1];
        changeLinks(channel);
    }
});

function changeLinks(channel) {
    var beforeURL = 'http://www.differentdomain.com/emailcheck.aspx?FormName=1881&e=<spanclass=emailclass>';

    var afterURL = '</span>&url=https://www.domain.com/order-page#us&page=us';

    $('a.LinkClicked').removeAttr('href');
    $("a.LinkClicked").click(function() {
        window.open(beforeURL + channel + afterURL);
    });
```

The HTML is simple:

```
<a class="LinkClicked" href="/order-page/">Link</a>
```

The problem right now is that the  tags are not loading in the URL once clicked. Also, this page is an aspx page, does that make a difference?

The final outcome should be to open a new page using the link, something like this based on the user's email address (so the email will be different each time, depending on the user):

```
http://www.differentdomain.com/emailcheck.aspx?FormName=1881&e=<spanclass=emailclass>email@usersemail.com</span>&url=https://www.domain.com/order-page#us&page=us
```

Comment: You need to encode stuff for the URL.  Dont' use reserved characters!

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, how would I encode stuff for the URL? and what are reserved characters?

Comment: @user1883431 For encoding URLS, see related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332872/how-to-encode-a-url-in-javascript

Comment: *'removes existing href'* from what? I've read your question a few times and I honestly don't understand what you want to happen. You want the link in the email to change, or a link on the page they're taken to *after* clicking the link in the email? And why are you passing HTML mark-up in a URL?

Comment: Your redirecting to a new page from the email url?  This should not be accomplished through javascript.  If you are using `aspx` you should be able to check the querystring in the page load function and `response.redirect` from there.

Comment: This question doesn't make much sense. Quote : 'and removes existing href and uses onclick function with new links.' wtf?

Comment: Yes, *and then what?* Step-by-step, as if you're explaining it to someone that has *no* idea at all what's going on in your code, use-case or work-flow. Because we don't.

Comment: someone clicks a link from an email with the URL: http://www.domain.com/page/?e=email@usersemail.com
Then,when they get to the page if the URL contains the email address in it(like the URL from the email), it takes away the <a href> so that they can't click thelink that is coded in, so now, using javascript when they click that same <a> it will go to a new URL created based on the email address in the URL from the email,like this: http://www.differentdomain.com/emailcheck.aspx?FormName=1881&e=<spanclass=emailclass>email@usersemail.com</span>&url=https://www.domain.com/order-page#us&page=us

Comment: I'm limited on characters... so the new URL would be like the last line I posted on this post